# Percentage/ Discounting present value

Tags: percentages

I have been taught that to increase and decrease a number by a percentage we do the following:
e.g.
Increase by 5% and decrease by 5%.
100 * 1.05 = 105. (increase)
100* 0.95 = 95 (decrease)
When I am looking at a present value formula we are told to do the following:

$$PV = \dfrac{FV}{(1+r)n}$$

Can someone explain to me why the two methods yield different results. Are they not essentially attempting to do the same thing i.e. reduce a given number by 5%?
100/1.05 = 95.23
100*0.95  = 95
I just can't seem to wrap my head around the concept, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: PV is present value, FV  is future value, so set PV=100 instead.

Comment: Example - If we are given a future value = 100 and we want to find the present value. 

Method 1. 100/1.05 = 95.23 (discounting by 5%)

Method 2. 100*0.95 = 95 (reducing by 5%) 

I'm unsure why these give two different results.